# PHP regex ampersand issue

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I use the following regex to validate a username (input type text in a registration form) in order to make sure that the username contains ONLY alphanumeric characters, dot, dash or underscore.

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_-]+$/',$my_name)) {  echo 'no_valid'; }
```

When I type in the text field for instance % or # or @ I get back correctly the error message that it's not a valid username, also the valid characters (.-_) are accepted, so it seems to work fine until the time I type & or +, then I can type any invalid character that I have already exclude before by using the preg_match.

Could anyone tell me why is this happening and how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine for me.

Comment: How is $my_name being set? ie `index.php?name=bob&x` gives name as `bob`. You may want to add a minimum length ie `/^[a-zA-Z0-9\._\-]{5,}$/` for string of 5 chars or more

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that I call this php regex by an ajax post on a keyup event of the input type username field. I don't know if this is an additional valuable info for you.

Comment: Why not just exclude the `&` and `+` altogether, or do a `preg_replace`? It's an option.

Comment: Yes it's an option, I tried already to replace the & and + with '' but this a very bad UX. I can't give an error message back to my user of what is doing wrong... in order to fix it and proceed.

Comment: you should check what **exactly** is passed to the variable $my_name, because the regex seems to be working fine in php.

Comment: I cheked it by using the js alert(my_name), it passes what you type.
For example **testuser&**

Comment: @paokg4 The user never needs to know ;-) everything runs in the background, away from prying eyes... as it were. In a `last resort` scenario, would be a way to go. What's in your form? Might help to see what's in there that could affect things.

Answer (score 5):

Problem is somewhere else. Your expression is correct. I tested with PHP. Since it happens with '&' character my guess would be that your data is not converted to URL safe characters before send. Try using encodeURI() function in JS.

Comment: +1 thought that too (see comment) but it doesn't explain the + (space) as it is not in the regex

Comment: Didn't work, as I mention before there is no url request, I use ajax post, I just pass the username as string, so I think there is no need for encodeURI(), please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I solved it but I still need an explanation, I will appreciate it if you or someone else can give me. The problem was on the ajax post data.

I had this line before to post the username, this worked for a months: 
`data: 'my_name='+ my_name`

Now I changed it to:
`data: { my_name: my_name}`
and it's working. Can anyone explain me why the & and + cause this issue when I use this: `data: 'my_name='+ my_name` instead of `data: { my_name: my_name}`

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z0-9\.\_-]+$/',urldecode($my_name))) {  echo 'no_valid'; }
```